# Can not add new custom attribute to order

Tags: php

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1.

Right now i am developing extension to add an attribute to the checkout page.

I am doing everything by this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento You can see the guide as an answer to the question.

So let me show all the files i've created:

1: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/Vshippingone/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
    </modules>

    <global> 
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <my_custom_input_field_one><to_order>*</to_order></my_custom_input_field_one>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <my_custom_input_field_one><to_quote>*</to_quote></my_custom_input_field_one>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Helper</class>
            </vshippingone>            
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>vshippingone_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </vshippingone>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <vshippingone_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_setup>
            <vshippingone_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_write>
            <vshippingone_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </vshippingone_read>
        </resources>

        <events>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
                <observers>
                    <vshippingone>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                        <method>saveCustomDataOne</method>
                    </vshippingone>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <vshippingone>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Block</class>
            </vshippingone>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

2: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/Vshippingone/Model/Observer.php:

```
<?PHP
class VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomDataOne($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getSession()->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_one', $event->getRequestModel()->getPost('my_custom_input_field_one'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

3: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/Vshippingone/sql/vshippingone_setup/mysql4-install-1.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

4: /app/etc/modules/VivasIndustries_Vshippingone.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I have not made any other files aka Helpers or anything else. No other changes i have made to this clean installed Magento. I have not installed any other extensions either.

**By my understanding i've added the following:**

In: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml - I've added the following line so i can see the input field in the checkout page, Search for `<input type="text" name="my_custom_input_field_one" id="my_custom_input_field_one"></input>`:

```
<?php /** @var $this Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available */ ?>
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
<?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <dl class="sp-methods">
    <?php $shippingCodePrice = array(); ?>
    <?php $_sole = count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1; foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
            <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                <?php $shippingCodePrice[] = "'".$_rate->getCode()."':".(float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>
                <li>
                   <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                    <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?></li></ul></li></ul>
                   <?php else: ?>
                        <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
                        <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>

                        <?php if ($_rate->getCode() === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()): ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                lastPrice = <?php echo (float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>;
                            //]]>
                        </script>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getMethodTitle()) ?>
                        <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                        <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                        <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                            (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </label>
                   <?php endif ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <input type="text" name="my_custom_input_field_one" id="my_custom_input_field_one"></input>
    </dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
        var shippingCodePrice = {<?php echo implode(',',$shippingCodePrice); ?>};
    <?php endif; ?>

    $$('input[type="radio"][name="shipping_method"]').each(function(el){
        Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){
            if (el.checked == true) {
                var getShippingCode = el.getValue();
                <?php if (!empty($shippingCodePrice)): ?>
                    var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];
                    if (!lastPrice) {
                        lastPrice = newPrice;
                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;
                    }
                    if (newPrice != lastPrice) {
                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);
                        lastPrice = newPrice;
                    }
                <?php endif; ?>
                checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;
                return false;
            }
       });
    });
//]]>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml:

I've added the following:

```
<?php if($_order->getMyCustomInputFieldOne()): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('My Custom Input Field One') ?></label></td>
    <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getMyCustomInputFieldOne() ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There is a very strange thing:

When i open `sales_flat_order` with PHPMyAdmin and i edit for example the last or any other order i can not modify the column `my_custom_input_field_one`. Whatever i post to the column and hit `Go` to make the edit everything goes fine without any errors displayed, but however the edit is not done.

Whatever i post to `my_custom_input_field_one` and after submitting the edit the column still holds `NULL` as a result. Somehow i can not edit that.

Checkout the structure:
[image]

When i remove the `Null` setting from the structure of `my_custom_input_field_one` i receive the following alert when trying to finish an order:

[image]

Here you can see the error i receive in exception.log: http://pastebin.com/93XWbLxy

I don't know where is my mistake and why i can not save the data inserted in the custom input.

Can you help me out resolve this problem and make the information inserted in the custom input to be saved in the order details ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the Magento logs for errors. Also make sure they're turned on

Comment: From where i can turn them on ?

Comment: The post that you link to is base off "how to add a field to the order admin" and not frontend. Therefore you are using the wrong observer (adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before)

Comment: Here you can see the error i receive in exception.log: http://pastebin.com/93XWbLxy

Comment: @R.S Can you post an answer with the correction which i have to make so i can fix it ? I am stuck on this like a whole day. Thanks!

Comment: What step is the field on?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Vi0TKUE.png Here you can see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong observer, which will never been trigger. You need to use a frontend observer

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
         <observers>
             <vshippingone>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                  <method>saveCustomDataOne</method>
             </vshippingone>
             ....
```

Try

In config.xml

```
<events>
    <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
         <observers>
             <vshippingone>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <class>vshippingone/observer</class>
                  <method>saveCustomDataOne</method>
             </vshippingone>
         </observers>
    </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
    ...
```

Update your observer to

```
<?PHP
class VivasIndustries_Vshippingone_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomDataOne($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_one', $event->getRequest()->getPost('my_custom_input_field_one'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: With this edit when i try to add an item to the cart i receive: http://i.imgur.com/LmNKPBi.png Somehow now i can not add any item to the cart. Here is my config.xml after the suggested by you edit: http://pastebin.com/t9ceNnAa

Comment: It's closed. Checkout the pastebin link for the current config.xml :)

Comment: Take a look at my update and undo the  changes to the observer

Comment: Same problem is still here. I can not add any item to the cart :)

Comment: That issue can not be cause by that change unless you have xml format issue

Comment: @R.S you forgot the closing observer tag, edited it. Might have caused the XML format issue

Comment: Okey i've made this change, but now when i click on `Continue` after posting any data in this input field at the `Shipping Method` step, i am redirected to `/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/`. Check out this screen: http://i.imgur.com/JgHVFlo.png . I do not know why but i am not going to the next step, but i am redirected back to the cart !?!? It is very strange!

Comment: This normally happen you you have a error in your ajax response

Comment: What you suggest now ?

Comment: It is not resolving the problem...

Comment: Now everything works FINE! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can i just ask which line of code is selecting from which input the data must be received to be saved into `my_custom_input_field_one` column ? Because right now i am trying to make this extension to get data from a select menu with name `shipping_address_id`. Thanks!

Comment: I dont understand what your askin

Comment: This `$quote->setData('my_custom_input_field_one' ..` save it to the quote table and `<fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote> ... ` copy it from the quote field to the order field

Comment: Right now, with this code the text inserted in input with name `my_custom_input_field_one` is inserted to MySQL column `my_custom_input_field_one`. My question is how can i select other input with different name and again insert the data to the same MySQL column `my_custom_input_field_one`. Thanks :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29172/discussion-between-r-s-and-tony-stark).